# File.exists?() returns false when It should be true?

Tags: ruby, file-io

I think I am doing this all wrong but if I am in directory `foo/` which is a child of `bar/` and I do:

`File.exists?("../somefile.rb")`

it returns false, when it should be true ... unless I am doing it wrong:

```
bar/
  somefile.rb
  foo/
    someotherfile.rb
```

`someotherfile.rb` is the one with the code to check if `somefile.rb` exists.

What am I doing wrong - I am trying to see if it exists, so I can open it.

Comment: It works fine here, please make sure the directory structure is indeed what you say it is. Also, make sure you did not change your working directory. `Dir.getwd` will return the current working directory so make sure that's indeed `bar/foo` in your case.

Comment: `File.exists?` is actually deprecated in ruby 2.1 - Use `File.exist?` instead

Answer (score 1):

If the process does not have permissions to tell whether a file exists it will return false. It may be possible to open a file, but not tell by normal methods if it exists.

source:- [File.exists() returns false when file exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919918/file-exists-returns-false-when-file-exists?rq=1)

Comment: The source you list is for java, not ruby.  While the same issues dealing with Windows OS may apply, seeing that syntax on your source page freaked me out until I realized they were discussing java.