# java.io.File exists() sometimes returns incorrect result

Tags: java, file-io

I came across one issue in java `file.exists()` gives incorrect result sometimes. I observed same behavior in our application when file actually exists till it returns `false`. I observed this behavior in GFS2 mounting directory.

Please suggest, if anyone knows alternative for this or to solve this issue advise me as earliest. I am using java 1.7.

Comment: If you do not have permissions the `file.exists()` will return false. rather use `file.getAbsoluteFile().exists() `

Comment: Can you please give me in brief how file.getabsoluteFile().exists() returns reliable result than File.exists(). If it is proved some where.

Answer (score 3):

In the case where you find `file.exists()` returns `false`
try using `file.getAbsoluteFile().exists()`, this will return true.

> The [getAbsolutePath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getAbsoluteFile%28%29) returns the absolute form of this abstract pathname.This is Equivalent to `new File(this.getAbsolutePath())`.

This question has answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919918/file-exists-returns-false-when-file-exists) but no accepted answer.

This appears to be a [bug](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do;:YfiG?bug_id=4483097)

> An ugly work-around is using getAbsoluteFile() on all File objects that came
>   from "unknown" sources