# Java: why using file.exists() is giving a false value even tho the path is complete?

Tags: java, file, exists

Well, I just started using `File` and I'm having a problem

**My Code:**

```
File file = new File("D:\\File\\TextFile.txt");

System.out.println(file.exists());
```

**Output:**
false

even tho I've got the file on that directory!

Comment: You sure that the path is correct? You sure that you haven't hidden known extensions or such?

Comment: Open D:\File in command prompt and run dir. It's quite possible you have a file TextFile.txt.ext i.e. your Windows may have been configured to hide extensions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [File.exists() returns false when file exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/919918/file-exists-returns-false-when-file-exists)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found the problem right after I posted.
It turned out that my windows is configured to hide extensions so the correct file name would be:

***D:\File\TextFile.txt.txt***

Comment: First thing I turn off -always. Whoever thought that would be a great idea at ms should be punished. Hard!